# How to Identify that an SQS Queue is working or empty

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS queue and before sending messages to this queue I need to identify that it has active messages in it. I am using the following typescript code to catch this.

```
const queueUrl = 'https://sqs.' + 'MY_QUEUE';
const sqsClient = new SQSClient({region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION});

const getQueueAttributesCommandInput: GetQueueAttributesCommandInput = {
  QueueUrl: queueUrl,
  AttributeNames: ['All']
};

const getQueueAttributesCommandOutput = await sqsClient.send(new GetQueueAttributesCommand(getQueueAttributesCommandInput));
if (getQueueAttributesCommandOutput.$metadata.httpStatusCode !== 200) {
  return new ErrorCustom(this.sqsFetchError, 400, {});
}

const approximateNumberOfMessages = +getQueueAttributesCommandOutput.Attributes['ApproximateNumberOfMessages'];
const approximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible = +getQueueAttributesCommandOutput.Attributes['ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible'];
const approximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed = +getQueueAttributesCommandOutput.Attributes['ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed'];
if (approximateNumberOfMessages + approximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible + approximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed !== 0) {
  return new ErrorCustom(this.sqsIsActivePleaseTryAgain, 400, {});
}
```

Is it a correct approach? If not how can I identify that if an SQS queue is active or empty?

On this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/confirm-queue-is-empty.html
It says that :

> When all of them are 0 for several minutes, the queue is empty.

I just want to ask that these attribute statistics are how real-time are like 10 seconds of empty results is enough.

Cheers.

Comment: Why do you wish to check the queue before sending a message?

Comment: This page confused me. https://sookocheff.com/post/messaging/dissecting-sqs-fifo-queues/

Comment: What is your actual concern? Is there a particular situation you need to avoid (eg sending a message out of order)? What would your program do if there is already a message in the queue? I do not recommend your current approach -- if you need to ensure FIFO ordering, then send messages to the SQS queue with the same `MessageGroupId`.

Comment: I have a very strict requirement that a bunch of messages which arrive to the system would be handled sequentially and these should not be grouped on a single lambda because if they are grouped a timeout will probably occur a very long running job. So with a buffer sqs I decided to check that the main SQS fifo is empty or not. I decided to send each jobs after one job is finished in one lambda time.

Comment: I do not recommend that approach. Instead, use a FIFO queue, have each message use the same `MessageGroupId` and set the **Batch Size** to 1 so that only one message is passed to the Lambda function. No other message with the same `MessageGroupId` will be sent to the Lambda function while a message with that ID is still being processed.

Comment: thank you very much I am checking the parameter. This one is the parameter that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your requirement is:

- Ensure each message is processed in strict order
- Do not send multiple messages to the Lambda function (for fear of timeout)

I would recommend:

- Use an Amazon SQS **FIFO** (First-In, First-Out) queue
- Set the **Batch Size** to 1 to only send a single message to the Lambda function
- Use the **same** `MessageGroupId` for each message -- this will ensure that Lambda does not process a message while another message with the same ID is being processed